# Can CreateFile() Open one file at the same time in two different thread

Tags: c, winapi, createfile

Can CreateFile() Open one file at the same time in two different thread

---

`void new_function(void * what)
{`

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile("c:\\tmp", GENERIC_ALL,FILE_SHARE_WRITE | 
                  FILE_SHARE_READ , NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD d = GetLastError();
    return ;
}
Sleep(10000);
```

}

`int main()
{`

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile("c:\\tmp", GENERIC_ALL,FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

Sleep(10000);
return 1;
```

}

---

every time it exits at the `GetLastError` position. and the error is `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (32, "The
process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
process.")

if i canot share open the file, then what is the use of the `FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ`

thanx

`The program environment is Win32 Vs2003`

Comment: You need to say which language, which operating system, which version.

Comment: Looks like C to me.  CreateFile is a Win32() API.  You would have liked him to better tag it... He is a 63 reputation user who joined 24 days ago.  Be peaceful.  Thanks for retagging it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The file handle is *always* shared between threads.  All you will need to do is merely use the handle as normal, but on two threads.

Your second call to `CreateFile()` fails because you ask for more access, `GENERIC_ALL`, than you allow for shared access, `FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ`.

If you instead requested only `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`, it would succeed.

The `CreateFile()` behavior will be the same if you call it on a single thread.

Comment: Thanx very much.........i change `GENERIC_ALL` to `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`. i get the right answer

Comment: Also you can add FILE_SHARE_DELETE. It depends on what do you want from your file.

Comment: You should not add FILE_SHARE_DELETE, because you want to request the least privilege needed.